# pass current instance of asp.net web page via InjectionConstructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

```
public class LogUtil : ILogUtility
{
   ... 
   public LogUtil(System.Type classType) 
   ....
}
```

From my WebForm1.aspx page code behind, PageLoad event, I am able to do the following successfully..

```
LogUtil logger = new LogUtil(this.GetType());
```

But when I attempt the following code from WebForm1.aspx, on pageload event..

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
System.Type type = this.GetType();

container.RegisterType<ILogUtility, LogUtil>(new InjectionConstructor(this.GetType()));  <--Error
```

at the above line, I get the following error...

**The type LogUtil does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (WebForm1).**

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass in the current instance of class via InjectionConstructor? Why am I able to pass in this.GetType() successfully directly into LogUtil constructor but I am uanble to do it via InjectionConstructor???

Comment: Is the goal to inject any class?  Why are you injecting a WebForm into your logger?  Some detail about what you are ultimately trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: confused about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yes.. I should be able to inject any class. This is actually for log4net implementation. Within the logger class for log4net, I have to do the following log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(classType);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by updating the constructor signature of my class as follows:

```
public class LogUtil : ILogUtility
{
   ... 
   public LogUtil(object classType)  
   ....
}
```

Comment: thanks.. all it takes is to 1)pause 2) deep thought 3) think logically .. some thing I need to practice more and more :)

Comment: Ha yeah I know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

On your Logger class, your type is the Logger class, so it works. It doesn't work on the webform, because this.GetType() is returning the type webform.

Comment: I have updated details in my question to make it more clear. Why am I able to pass System.Type directly into LogUtil but I am unable to do it via InjectionConstructor???